# What exactly went wrong on regression coefficient p values for multicollinearity case?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

The following code shows a toy example for linear regression. I made almost identical columns and plug into linear model.

If we look at the significant code of the p value, I feel counter intuitive that **if we use two significant variables but correlated, then both of them became not significant**.

what is the reason (the violated assumption) we have the wrong p value? Also the matrix condition number is high, is the numerical problem causing this?

```
> mtcars$wt2<-mtcars$wt+runif(32)*1e-5
> summary(lm(mpg~wt,mtcars))
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.5432 -2.3647 -0.1252  1.4096  6.8727 
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.2851     1.8776  19.858  < 2e-16 ***
wt           -5.3445     0.5591  -9.559 1.29e-10 ***


> summary(lm(mpg~wt+wt2,mtcars))
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + wt2, data = mtcars)
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.4542 -2.0952 -0.2647  1.8365  6.3834 
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      38.71       2.20  17.593   <2e-16 ***
wt           206811.44  169901.52   1.217    0.233    
wt2         -206816.87  169901.60  -1.217    0.233
```

Comment: In what sense is any of these p-values "wrong"?  The *correct* test in the second model would be a likelihood ratio or F-test of the *pair* of variables.  Because the very meaning of a multiple regression model changes as variables are included or excluded, the t-tests in the second model *are totally different* than the t-test in the first model, even though the two models have a variable in common.

Comment: @whuber thanks for educating me. I use the word "wrong" is because I think the results is counterintuitive for me. I may revise the question alter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the use of p-values in regression for significance testing  should be avoided. http://www.nature.com/news/scientific-method-statistical-errors-1.14700

Said that  let's discuss the problem from a strictly mathematical point of view.

Given a dataset $(X, y)$ the least square estimator computes the projection of $y$ on the columns of $X$. If this projection on one of the columns is large enough and well defined then the p-value of the associated variable will be significant.

In your second case you have two columns that are identical. As a consequence the cost function associate to the linear regression will probably be very flat for combinations of `wt` and `wt2`.

I'm not sure but I would say that it has the same values for all the linear combinations for which $\alpha* wt + \beta *wt_2 \sim -5.34 *wt$

As a consequence the variance of the estimated coefficients explodes and make the p-value larger than 0.05.

I am not 100% sure that all what I wrote is true but I am quiet confident it is. You can verify it numerically